# Android: Detect remote command to control music

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-broadcastreceiver

I've built a music player app for android. I want it to detect remote commands like a play next command from headphone button. How do I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

As per android documentation 
**To respond to media button clicks, you need to register a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest that listens for this action broadcast as shown below.**

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

[Take a look](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html)